How to extend btrfs subvolumes space using separate SSD?
$ lsblk -f -o +SIZE
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS           SIZE
sda                                                                                                    223,6G
zram0                                                                              [SWAP]        8G
nvme0n1                                                                                      238.5G
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat   FAT32       7282-A72B                             581.5M     3% /boot/efi   600M
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4   1.0         98a490b5-f309-4401-9952-f706a1277caf  536.6M    38% /boot         1G
├─nvme0n1p3 btrfs              c2a5b63b-80bc-42f7-9672-8be1ba8b6a8e  433.1G     2% /home     219.9G
│                                                                                  /         
└─nvme0n1p4 swap   1     swap  7b318eeb-133c-4dd7-a34b-3c78277450f8                [SWAP]       17G

$ sudo btrfs filesystem show /dev/nvme0n1p3
Label: none  uuid: c2a5b63b-80bc-42f7-9672-8be1ba8b6a8e
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 15.22GiB
        devid    1 size 219.86GiB used 20.02GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p3

$ sudo btrfs subvolume list .
ID 256 gen 1752 top level 5 path @
ID 257 gen 1752 top level 5 path @home

So I want to extend available space for these two subvolumes (@, @home) via /dev/sda (empty, not formatted now).
Could you plz point me how to achieve this?
UPD
Thanks a lot @KamilMaciorowski much appreciated for your comment!
sudo btrfs device add -f /dev/sda /home

done only for home mountpoint but seems like it affected both @ and @home subvolumes (according to blivet-gui).
Is it related for all of these mountpoints now:
/, /home, /var/lib/snapd/snap


$ lsblk -f -o +SIZE
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
                                                                                               SIZE
sda         btrfs              c2a5b63b-80bc-42f7-9672-8be1ba8b6a8e                          223.6G
zram0                                                                              [SWAP]        8G
nvme0n1                                                                                      238.5G
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat   FAT32       7282-A72B                             581.5M     3% /boot/efi   600M
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4   1.0         98a490b5-f309-4401-9952-f706a1277caf  536.6M    38% /boot         1G
├─nvme0n1p3 btrfs              c2a5b63b-80bc-42f7-9672-8be1ba8b6a8e  433.1G     2% /home     219.9G
│                                                                                  /         
└─nvme0n1p4 swap   1     swap  7b318eeb-133c-4dd7-a34b-3c78277450f8                [SWAP]       17G


$ sudo btrfs filesystem show /dev/nvme0n1p3
Label: none  uuid: c2a5b63b-80bc-42f7-9672-8be1ba8b6a8e
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 8.73GiB
        devid    1 size 219.86GiB used 13.02GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p3
        devid    2 size 223.57GiB used 0.00B path /dev/sda


man btrfs-device

@KamilMaciorowski sudo btrfs device add -f /dev/sda /home done only for home mountpoint but seems like it affected both @ and @home (I'll append details to question)

(1) The command adds the device to the filesystem, not to the subvolume, not to the mountpoint. (2) Does the command answer your question? If so, it should be an answer, not a part of the question. If not, then what is the problem now?

@KamilMaciorowski it is weird that argument is "mountpoint" if it's ignored ... why not uid of btrfs volume? Anyway I'm happy with that result and you could post answer =)

@madzohan well it's not obviously ignored, but used as a "reference" (which is probably considered more convenient by most users than any UUID) to denote the target filesystem, and it works regardless of whether the mountpoint is mounted with its top-level subvolume or some other one (which is also more convenient than having the latter case prohibited, albeit it might then look "semantically odd").
